# `locate` wildcard strange behavior - why?

Tags: linux, command-line, wildcards, locate, coreutils

`locate "*.png"` returns all files ending with `.png`, as expected.

`locate "test.*"` doesn't return anything, but there are files named `test` in my system.

`locate "*test"` returns all files ending with `test`, as expected.

`locate "test*"` doesn't return anything, but there are files starting with `test` in my system.

Why do wildcards seem to work only for "ending with"?

Comment: Did you rebuild the locatedb after creating the files that match `test*` and `test.*`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: yes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `locate "test.*"` doesn't return anything, but there are files named test in my system.

`.` is treated as dot, not as in regex's as an arbitrary character, so `test.*` does not match `test`, but `test.foo`.

> `locate "test*"` doesn't return anything, but there are files starting with `test` in my system.

locate stores *the full path to the file*, so to find files starting with test, you should use `locate "*/test*"`.

The last point might be confusing, as `locate foo` finds anything including `foo`, so the pattern gets interpreted as `*foo*`. It seems that the pattern is not enclosed in stars, if there is already one wildcard in the pattern.

*Disclaimer*: I did some test and these are my conclusions, I cannot prove them by citing the man page, which seems very rudimentary.

Comment: In my `man locate` I have: _If  --regex is not specified, PATTERNs can contain globbing characters. If any PATTERN contains no globbing characters, locate  behaves  as  if the pattern were \*PATTERN*._